# Como hacer referencia a una Class Componente por medio de un string en Angular

Tags: angular, api, typescript, component

Tengo lo siguiente en mi AppComponent, lo resumo para no complicar la explicación.

```
import { PageComponent } from './page.component';

const componente = 'PageComponent';

this.router.config.unshift({
  path: '',
  component: componente,
  children: [{
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './pages.module#PageComponentsModule'
  }]});
```

La consola me manda el siguiente error:

```
ERROR TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Type<any>'.
```

Es obvio que si mando: component: PageComponent funciona pero el objetivo es mandar ese parámetro por medio de una variable string. Esto es porque recibo ese parámetro por medio de una API.

Alguien me puede apoyar a mandar ese parámetro por medio de un string, ya he intentado algunas opciones pero nigua con éxito.

Saludos cordiales.

Comment: ¿Qué estás intentando, modificar las rutas dinámicamente?

Comment: si, generar rutas dentro de un componente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aunque las rutas sean dinámicas, los componentes ya tienen que existir y estar declarados en el módulo, por lo que en realidad tienes ya una lista de posibles candidatos *estática*, que podrías poner en un mapa:

```
const componente = 'PageComponent';

const mapaComponentes= {
  'PageComponent': PageComponent,
  'OtroComponente': OtroComponente
  ...
}

this.router.config.unshift({
  path: '',
  component: mapaComponentes[componente],
  children: [{
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './pages.module#PageComponentsModule'
  }]});
```

Comment: Gracias, es buena solución.